# How to follow 302 redirects while still getting page information when scraping using Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, http-status-code-302

Been wrestling with trying to get around this 302 redirection. First of all, the point of this particular part of my scraper is to get the next page index so I can flip through pages. The direct URLS aren't available for this site, so I cant just move on to the next or anything; in order to continue scraping the actual data using a parse_details function, I have to go through each page and simulate requests.

This is all pretty new to me, so I made sure to try anything I could find first. I have tried various settings ("REDIRECT_ENABLED":False, altering handle_httpstatus_list, etc.) but none are getting me through this. Currently I'm trying to follow the location of the redirection, but this isn't working either. 
Here is an example of one of the potential solutions I've tried following.

```
try:
    print('Current page index: ', page_index)
except: # Will be thrown if page_index wasnt found due to redirection.
    if response.status in (302,) and 'Location' in response.headers:
        location = to_native_str(response.headers['location'].decode('latin1'))
         yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(location), method='POST', callback=self.parse)
```

The code, without the details parsing and such, is as follows:

```
def parse(self, response):
    table = response.css('td> a::attr(href)').extract()
    additional_page = response.css('span.page_list::text').extract()
        for string_item in additional_page: # The text has some non-breaking 
    # spaces (&nbsp) to ignore. We want the text representing the 
            # current page index only.
            char_list = list(string_item)
            for char in char_list:
                if char.isdigit():
                    page_index = char
                    break # Now that we have the current page index, we 
    # can back out of this loop.

        # Below is where the code breaks; it cannot find page_index since it is 
    # not getting to the site for scraping after redirection.
        try:    
            print('Current page index: ', page_index)


    # To get to the next page, we submit a form request since it is all 
    # setup with javascript instead of simlpy giving a URL to follow.
    # The event target has 'dgTournament' information where the first 
    # piece is always '_ctl1' and the second is '_ctl' followed by 
    # the page index number we want to go to minus one (so if we want 
    # to go to the 8th page, its '_ctl7').
    # Thus we can just plug in the current page index which is equal to 
    # the next we want to hit minus one.

    # Here is how I am making the requests; they work until the (302) 
    # redirection...
    form_data = {"__EVENTTARGET": "dgTournaments:_ctl1:_ctl" + page_index,
                     "__EVENTARGUMENT": {";;AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.50731.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e:en-US:ec0bb675-3ec6-4135-8b02-a5c5783f45f5:de1feab2:f9cec9bc:35576c48"}}

    yield FormRequest(current_LEVEL, formdata=form_data, method="POST", callback=self.parse, priority=2)
```

Alternatively, a solution may be to follow pagination in a different way, instead of making all of these requests?
The original link is

```
https://m.tennislink.usta.com/TournamentSearch/searchresults.aspx?typeofsubmit=&action=2&keywords=&tournamentid=&sectiondistrict=&city=&state=&zip=&month=0&startdate=&enddate=&day=&year=2019&division=G16&category=28&surface=&onlineentry=&drawssheets=&usertime=&sanctioned=-1&agegroup=Y&searchradius=-1
```

if anyone is able to help.

Comment: Can you add url before and after redirection? Maybe there another domain which does not allow in your spider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to follow 302 requests instead you can do a POST request and receive the details of the page. The following code prints the data in the first 5 pages:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = 'https://m.tennislink.usta.com/TournamentSearch/searchresults.aspx'

pages=5

for i in range(pages):

    params={'year':'2019','division':'G16','month':'0','searchradius':'-1'}
    payload={'__EVENTTARGET': 'dgTournaments:_ctl1:_ctl'+str(i)}

    res= requests.post(url,params=params,data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')

    table=soup.find('table',id='ctl00_mainContent_dgTournaments')

    #pretty print the table contents
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        for column in row.find_all('td'):
            text = ', '.join(x.strip() for x in column.text.split('\n') if x.strip()).strip()
            print(text)
        print('-'*10)
```

Comment: thats what i was doing in scrapy... doing it this way still ends up going to the redirected err pages and giving nothing...

Comment: yea doing that exact code prints nothing after the fourth page index

Comment: I appreciate all the help! Still getting redirects that mess it up after about a minute but ill check it up as a thanks for you spending so much time trying. Appreciated it!

Comment: I appreciate it and prolly they're limiting the requests try using a sleep time between the scraping